# Where to put std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++builder, clang++

I am planning a new C++11 Win32/64 project with C++Builder 10.1 (Clang 3.3) and thinking about implementing it in the most portable way when it comes to the core functions, so I'd like to use UTF-8 for the `std::string` encoding (and also, because it's the default encoding for [SQLiteCpp](https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp), the SQLite C++ wrapper I intend to use).

For interacting with the Win-API I decided to use the `.to_bytes()`and `.from_bytes()` functions from `<codecvt>`'s and `<locale>`'s `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>`.

So, now I'd like to know, what are the best practices where to place the converter object.

Should I give it it's own unit and namespace, e.g.

**.h:**

```
...
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

namespace cnv
{
    extern std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> wcu8;
}
...
```

**.cpp:**

```
...
namespace cnv
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> wcu8;
}
...
```

and include it everywhere to use `cnv::wcu8.to_bytes(xyz)` where needed?

Or is it better to create an instance within each function implementation where I need to convert between encodings?

Comment: Why do you need it portable if your only intention is WIn32/64? If that's the case, you might as well forget converting and just use wstring.

Comment: It's for Windows *for now* and may be compiled for other systems in the future.

Comment: My experience with `std::wstring_convert` is that it is not very well supported by GCC and clang. Most notably the default compilers on Travis CI choke on including the `codecvt` header. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't store the `std::wstring_convert` in a global variable because that's not thread-safe and doesn't buy you much. There might be a performance hit with instantiating `std::wstring_convert` everytime you need it, but that should not be your primary concern at the beginning (premature optimization).

So I'd just wrap that thing into functions:

```
std::wstring utf8_to_wstr( const std::string& utf8 ) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> wcu8;
    return wcu8.from_bytes( utf8 );
}

std::string wstr_to_utf8( const std::wstring& utf16 ) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> wcu8;
    return wcu8.to_bytes( utf16 );
}
```

You have to catch `std::range_error` exception somewhere. It can be thrown by `std::wstring_convert` if the conversion fails for some reason (invalid code points, etc.).

If you hit performance bottlenecks regarding string conversions later, you can still instantiate `std::wstring_convert` directly at critical points in your code, e. g. outside of a long running loop that converts many strings.